# How to set animated scrollTop and scrollLeft values using a formula?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, formula

I have the following code...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr2W9/)

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    height:5000px;
    width:5000px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-image:url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/purty_wood.png);
    /* I used a background image so the scroll effect was more obvious */
}

#button {
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}

#item {
    position:absolute;
    height:250px;
    width:750px;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:3000px;
    left:2000px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="button"></div>
        <div id="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#button').click(function() { 
    $('#container').animate({
       'scrollTop':  '2990px'
    },{duration: 1000, queue: false});
    $('#container').animate({
       'scrollLeft':  '1990px'
    },{duration: 1000, queue: false});
});
```

As it currently works, when the blue button is pressed, the container scrolls to 2990px top and 1990px left, and the yellow item comes into view (leaving a 10px gap on the top and left sides of it), which is what I want it to do.

But, I'm wondering whether I can change this into a formula, so that it sets the scrollTop and scrollLeft values based on the left and top positioning of the item div. Allowing me to change the left and top positioning of the div without having to worry about editing my jquery.

I can see the formula in my head, but just don't know how to implement it into jQuery. The formula should be something like...

```
'scrollTop' = (("#item" top) - 10px)
```

instead of

```
'scrollTop':  '2990px'
```

and

```
'scrollLeft' = (("#item" left) - 10px)
```

instead of

```
'scrollLeft':  '1990px'
```

So it finds the values of 'top' and 'left' for the #item div, then subtracts 10 pixels from them.

I just don't know how to write that formula into my jQuery as I'm not very proficient with it yet.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the position of the element using `.position()` or `.offset()`.

```
$('#button').click(function() { 
    $('#container').animate({
        'scrollTop':  $('#item').position().top - 10
    },{duration: 1000, queue: false});
    $('#container').animate({
        'scrollLeft':  $('#item').position().left - 10
    },{duration: 1000, queue: false});
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cr2W9/2/